# rename file with "previous weekday"

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible for a batch file to rename all files in a directory by appending the date of previous weekday to the end of the filename?

for example, if i ran it on Monday 2/25/12, it would add "_022213" to the end of the filenames in the directory.

Thanks...

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Well, I know how to simply rename the files:  
rename "c:\test.txt" _%Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-2,4%.txt

but I'm not sure how to calculate the date for the previous weekday.

Comment: You'll have to borrow from vbscript.  The DateAdd function will let you subtract 1 weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo wd = Weekday^(Date^(^), vbSunday^)>yesterday.vbs
echo if wd ^< 3 then dif = -1 - wd else dif = -1 >>yesterday.vbs
echo d = dateadd^("d", dif, Date^(^)^)>>yesterday.vbs
echo wscript.echo DatePart^("yyyy",d^) ^& " " ^& DatePart^("m", d^) ^& " " ^& DatePart^("d", d^) >>yesterday.vbs
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%I in ('cscript /nologo yesterday.vbs') do (
    set year=%%I
    if %%J leq 9 (set month=0%%J) else set month=%%J
    if %%K leq 9 (set day=0%%K) else set day=%%K
)
del yesterday.vbs
set yesterday=%month%%day%%year:~-2%
for %%I in (*) do (
    set base=%%~nI
    echo !base:~-7!| findstr "^_[0-9]*$" >NUL && set base=!base:~0,-7!
    ren "%%I" "!base!_!yesterday!%%~xI"
)
```

There's no native function in Windows batch scripting that will let you perform math on dates.  VBscript has some nifty date math functions though.  DateAdd will let you add or subtract by the year, the quarter, the month, or several other intervals.  "w" specifies work day.  [More info](http://ss64.com/vb/dateadd.html).  *Update: apparently "w" doesn't mean what it seems like it should mean.  Script updated to perform the math manually.*

You can borrow from vbscript by echoing the vbscript to a .vbs file, then capturing the output of `cscript /nologo vbsfile` with a `for` loop.  See how that works?

Then just piece together `[basename]_[yesterday with slashes stripped][extension]`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  I assume there is an easy way to change the month and year to 2 digits?

Comment: Done.  I also added a check to see whether a date was already appended, and if so, strip it before adding a new one.

Comment: hmmm...i just ran this today, and it appended Sunday's date.  Not sure what went wrong?

Comment: @kmfdm - Apparently vbscript's "weekday" doesn't mean "work week day" as I thought it did.  I updated the script to perform the check for weekend.  Try it now please.

Answer (score 0):

For a batch only solution see 
https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/4666270

Here is how to use the batch script method in the link.

```
@echo off
if /i "%Date:~0,3%"=="Sun" ( call :DaysAgo 2 ) else (
    if /i "%Date:~0,3%"=="Mon" ( call :DaysAgo 3 ) else ( call :DaysAgo 1 )
)
echo %Year% %Month% %Day%
```

Comment: This would work correctly if I only run it on weekdays, correct?   Looks like running on a Sunday would pull Saturday's date.

Comment: Ok I updated it, so that when run on Sunday it selects Friday.