# Renaming and Formatting Excel worksheet with batch file

Tags: excel, batch-file

Is it possible to create a **batch file** that will do the following?

1. Rename a single sheet in an Excel file (*not* the Excel workbook/file itself)
2. Apply simple formatting to an Excel file - e.g., apply a Font and Font Size to the entire workbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two files: a batch file, and a VBScript file that is invoked by the batch file.  It's easy to manipulate Excel's workings in VBS.

**modder.bat**

```
:Start
   @Echo off
   CScript modder.vbs
:End
```

**modder.vbs**

```
'launch Excel and open file
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("c:\temp\filename.xls")
'turn off screen alerts
xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'loop through sheets
For Each Worksheet In xlFile.Worksheets 
   'change sheet to desired worksheet name
   If Worksheet.Name = "SheetToRename" Then
      Worksheet.Name = "NewName"
   End If
   'change all sheets to desired font 
   With Worksheet.Cells.Font 
       .Name = "Verdana" 
       .Size = 12
   End With 
Next  
'save, close, then quit
xlFile.Close True
xlObj.Quit
```

**modder.vbs** (with workday() function, as requested)

```
'launch Excel and open file
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("c:\temp\filename.xls")
'turn off screen alerts
xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'loop through sheets
For Each Worksheet In xlFile.Worksheets 
   'change sheet to desired worksheet name
   If Worksheet.Name = "SheetToRename" Then
      'get prior workday
      dPriorWorkday = xlObj.Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now, -1)
      'format as necessary (I used ISO 8061)
      Worksheet.Name = Year(dPriorWorkday) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(dPriorWorkday),2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(dPriorWorkday),2)
   End If
   'change all sheets to desired font 
   With Worksheet.Cells.Font 
       .Name = "Verdana" 
       .Size = 12
   End With 
Next  
'save, close, then quit
xlFile.Close True
xlObj.Quit
```

**Revision for partial sheet name**

```
   If Left(Worksheet.Name,12) = "Target Sheet" Then
      'get prior workday
      dPriorWorkday = xlObj.Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now, -1)
      'format as necessary (I used ISO 8061)
      Worksheet.Name = "Target Sheet " & Year(dPriorWorkday) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(dPriorWorkday),2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(dPriorWorkday),2)
   End If
```

Comment: that is very helpful, thanks!

In another question, I got some help renaming a file based on the previous weekday:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011081/rename-file-with-previous-weekday

Is there an easy way to combine these 2?  To rename the sheet name to the Previous Weekday?

Comment: Can I use wildcards in the sheetname in the "If Worksheet.Name = "SheetToRename"" section?

Comment: Not exactly, but you can approximate similar behavior with string comparisons or a regular expression. Can you give a precise example of how you'd want the wildcard scenario to work?

Comment: The sheet names are set text that never changes, followed by the date in YYYY-MM-DD format.  Basically, what I'd like to do is use this to update the sheet name with the previous weekday date.  Not sure if wildcards are required for that (to replace the old date).